# The routing doesn't appear

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Hy ! I'm trying to configure my route for my new comoponent called `gotosearch.component`. Hence, I have to add some codes chunks.

First , I import my class called `GotosearchComponent` from my path.

Second , I have to declare the path in `RouterModule.forRoot` in `NgModule`.

Third , I have to declare my component in declarations section.

However, while I'm running , I click on `Go to search` button, the page loaded but **the path remains the same**.

Well , I bring together my 3 components in one component called NavBarComponent ..! I would like to let the function goTo empty !!
How can I change the path? I need your help, please.

PS: the other three paths which are displayed in my `app.module.ts` work perfectly!

```
/compaign
/script
/home
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router' ; // Configuring routing added
import { SearchAppComponent } from './search-app.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav/navbar.component';
import { CompaignComponent} from './shared/compaign.component';
import { ScriptComponent} from './shared/script.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchComponent} from './shared/SearchBar.component';
import { GotosearchComponent} from'./shared/Gotosearch.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([   //Configuring routing added
      { path: 'home', component:SearchComponent},
      { path: 'script', component:ScriptComponent},                     
      { path: 'compaign' , component:CompaignComponent},
      { path: 'gotoSearch', component:GotosearchComponent}
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    SearchComponent,
    SearchAppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    CompaignComponent,
    ScriptComponent,
    GotosearchComponent
  ],
 bootstrap: [SearchAppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can there be a typo in `gotoSearch`? Angular routes are case sensitive. So maybe the route needs to be `gotosearch`?

Comment: Check console logs to see if you have wrong mapping.

Comment: @Nirav no there isnt

Comment: Can you please post the code which triggers routing? Everything seems fine in the code you posted.

Comment: @Nirav which code ??!! the only one is in app.module.ts ?? can yo clarify your point ??

Comment: component which has **Go to search** button as you've mentioned "However, while I'm running , I click on Go to search button, the page loaded but the path remains the same"

Comment: It would be better if you can create demo app on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). It will help to find the real problem easily.

Comment: @Nirav I bring together my three comoponent in a component called navbarComponent ..!! so in my template navbarcomponent.html ihave those three code lines : <li><a href="" (click)="goTo($event, 'compaign')">Compaign</a></li>  |||||||||   <li><a href="" (click)="goTo($event, 'script')">Script</a></li> ||||||||||||| <li><a href="" (click)="goTo()">Go To Search</a></li> <!-- Serach-->

Comment: Can you please edit the question with this NavBarComponent. Also, Please include `goTo` function. I think, you missed to pass arguments.. Try `goTo($event, 'gotoSearch')`.

Comment: Yes Indeed , it works now ..!! Many thanks (Y) @Nirav

Comment: Why do you use `(click)` when you have `[routerLink]`? You can do it like: `<a href="" [routerLink]="['gotoSearch']">Go To Search</a>`

Comment: I am glad it worked. However, @HarunYilmaz has a valid point. It is better to use **routerLink** instead of having function to navigate. I assume, you might be doing some validation check, which also can be done using [Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)